# Jquery / HTML fail, popup window code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, popup

I have Jquery Jplayer that streams an online radio and I have a popup button to open a new instance of the radio to let users navigate through a site with the built radio player pause at every page load.

The code below is the javascript function I've tried to get the new window up in the center of the screen. I did work ... and now for some reason does not.

The link is hidden on parent page load and is unhidden by another image (which works fine).

```
 function ListenPopOut() {
    var pageURL = "Radio.php";
    var title = "Radio";
    var w = 436;
    var h = 340;

    var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
    window.open (pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, 
    status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, width='+w+', 
    height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left, false);
 };

<a href="javascript:;" class="popup-foot" onclick="ListenPopOut()"
 title="popup">popup</a>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbNaV/4/).
Any ideas? what is wrong?

UPDATE: Missing link to jquery in original code, sorry for noob mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fiddle does not work because you get this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ListenPopOut is not defined
```

Reason for the error, you are running it onload in the fiddle, means method is local. Change it to head and it will run.

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbNaV/9/)

Comment: Thanks I've also found my original code had a link missing to my jquery file, D'oh